# iFrame's pdf content gets loaded twice in Chrome and Opera

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, iframe, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I have an iframe inside a modal-body. Every time I open the modal and look into the Network tab in Chrome or Opera's inspect element, I see that the pdf file get loaded twice: first one OK, second time Cancel (screenshot: [console_screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSosG.png), we're using Durandal framework). It happens in Chrome and Opera, not Safari or Firefox.

HTML code below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <iframe src="pdf/helloworld.pdf" width="100%"></iframe>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can only assume this is browser's issue ??? I've been searching everywhere and tried different stuff but nothing seems to solve this. Anyone had this before ? or any suggestion to get rid of the double loading ?

Comment: I did a work around this:
- Create another html (for example, call it embedPDF.html), put the PDF source into an `embed` tag: `<embed src="pdf/helloworld.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"/>`
- In the main html, put the path of embedPDF.html into the modal-body iframe like so: `<iframe  id="pdf-frame" src="somePath/embedPDF.html" width="100%"></iframe>`